# File Modal Pop-up On ID Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just after some advice.

I am trying to pop up a file modal dialog box after clicking an image. For some reason, in my browsers (IE, FF, Chrome) it doesn't seem to be working.

I have tried it in a fiddle and it seems to be working so not sure if I am doing something wrong.

This is what I have in the form:

```
<input type='file' name='photo' id='pu' class='photoupload'>
<img src='http://placehold.it/150x150' id='photo' alt='Image unavailable for $fn $ln' title='Image unavailable for $fn $ln'/>
```

This is what I have in the script:

```
$('#np').on('click', function()
    {
        $('#pu').click();
        console.log('Hit');
    });
```

I have tried it right after the document.ready function and I have also tried it with the window.load function

Both times it will log to the console, but for some reason it will not pop up a file modal dialog box. Like I said, I have tried it in a fiddle and it seems to be working. I have also tried copying it from other fiddles and it just doesn't want to work in the browsers.

Is there something simple I am missing?

My jQuery version is 1.9.0 with the migrate plugin 1.2.1 also.

I just cannot figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have duplicate id's in your page. Replace them with classes and you'll have better luck.

Comment: I only have unique ID's on my page. I have #np as a div, #pu as file upload and #photo for the actual photo. I have changed them and used classes and it still does the same. Like I say, it works in the fiddle so thought it might be something simple I may be missing

Comment: Are you looking for Model popup like File dialog ?

Comment: Yeah, I am wanting to click on the image and then then file dialog box popup. It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/wilcochris/LPQwP/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This.

```
$('#photo').on('click', function()    {
    $('#pu').click();      
});
```

[**Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dubeynee/5axS6/)

Comment: Hmmm, it must just be an issue on placement as this isn't working in the browser either. Oh well. Cheers